# Passing Variable into awk gsub

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, awk

I have this command
Here

```
vovar=OBJECTS
prvar="$(awk '/'"$vovar"'/,/}/ {gsub("$vovar"," "); gsub("}",": %s,"); gsub("{"," ");gsub(",",": %s,");print}' temp1)"
```

Contents of temp1

```
ciscoFlashCopyCompletionTrap NOTIFICATION-TYPE
        OBJECTS   
                { 
                ciscoFlashCopyStatus  
                }
        STATUS  current
        DESCRIPTION
                "A ciscoFlashCopyCompletionTrap is sent at the 
                completion of a flash copy operation if such a trap 
                was requested when the operation was initiated.
                "
        ::= { ciscoFlashMIBTraps 1 }
```

What I want the command to do

```
                ciscoFlashCopyStatus  
                : %s: %s,
```

What it actually does

```
        OBJECTS   

                ciscoFlashCopyStatus  
                : %s: %s,
```

How can I change my awk command so  that I can get what I want?

Comment: use `-v` param to pass variables into awk.

Comment: Yep! tried that already. Still getting the same output with OBJECTS written in the first line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used `vovar` outside single quotes for the first time, but not the second time:

```
... awk '/'"$vovar"'/,/}/ {gsub("$vovar"," ") ...
```

If you'd been consistent:

```
$ awk '/'"$vovar"'/,/}/ {gsub("'"$vovar"'"," "); gsub("}",": %s,"); gsub("{"," ");gsub(",",": %s,");print}' foo


                ciscoFlashCopyStatus  
                : %s: %s,
```

Comment: Ah damn it. Sorry about this.

Comment: You are too fast for me ;)